# Unmet dependencies with python3

Tags: server, gnome, dependencies, gui, python3

My server is currently running Ubuntu Server 15.10. Yesterday I tried installing Gnome GUI with the command

```
sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
```

Now whenever I try to upgrade I get these errors

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/fruitywifi is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.3-1) but 3.4.3-4ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running **apt-get -f install** gives me this

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/fruitywifi is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaacs0 libass5 libbluray1 libcec3 libenca0 libglew1.10 liblockdev1 libmad0 libmicrohttpd10 libplatform1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libssh-4 libva-x11-1
  libxss1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpython3-stdlib python3
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3-stdlib python3
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1089 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...done.
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...done.
Checking init scripts...
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.0:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64:
 libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.4-minimal:
 python3.4-minimal depends on libpython3.4-minimal (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1); however:
  Package libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.4-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.4-minimal (>= 3.4.3-1); however:
  Package python3.4-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0:amd64
 libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
 python3.4-minimal
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After all that the GUI doesnt even boots right so I want to remove it and try a different one but whenever I try to remove it I get this

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install -y
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/fruitywifi is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'software-center' instead of 'gnome-app-install'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.3-1) but 3.4.3-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Don't know what else to try.

---

`$ lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

`$ uname -a`

```
Linux ltserver 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:04:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`$ apt-cache policy python3-minimal`

```
python3-minimal:
  Installed: 3.4.3-4ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.4.3-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.3-4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`$ sudo apt-cache policy python3`

```
python3:
  Installed: 3.4.3-1
  Candidate: 3.4.3-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.4.3-4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.4.3-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

`$ sudo apt-get download python3`
`$ sudo dpkg -i python3_*.deb`

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/fruitywifi is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
dpkg: regarding python3_3.4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb containing python3, pre-dependency problem:
 python3 pre-depends on python3-minimal (= 3.4.3-4ubuntu1)
  python3-minimal latest configured version is 3.4.3-1.

dpkg: error processing archive python3_3.4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing python3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3_3.4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

`$ sudo apt-get install -f`

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/fruitywifi is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaacs0 libass5 libbluray1 libcec3 libenca0 libglew1.10 liblockdev1
  libmad0 libmicrohttpd10 libplatform1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libssh-4
  libva-x11-1 libxss1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpython3-stdlib python3
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3-stdlib python3
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1089 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...done.
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...done.
Checking init scripts...
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.0:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64:
 libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.4-minimal:
 python3.4-minimal depends on libpython3.4-minimal (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1); however:
  Package libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.4-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.4-minimal (>= 3.4.3-1); however:
  Package python3.4-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0:amd64
 libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
 python3.4-minimal
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy python3-minimal`

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy python3`

Comment: Ok I added the results.

Comment: `apt-get download libssl1.0.0 libpython3.4-minimal; sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0*.deb libpython3.4-minimal*.deb` – you need no `sudo` for download.

Comment: Not longer interested?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when running apt-get anything after upgrading to 15.10. Running

```
sudo apt-get install python3 libpython3-stdlib
```

Got me passed that problem. At the moment

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

is still running, so I do not know that it is all good yet, but at least it is progress.